# How can I keep track of pet food recalls?

Tags: diet, recall

Though we don't usually like to think about it, recalls on commercial pet foods occasionally happen. It hurts a lot to find out that your pet might be affected by such a recall. I feel like I read about recalls more often on news sites or blogs than on the manufacturer websites (if they even do list them).

What is the best way to find out about and keep track of pet food recalls?

Comment: @Baarn, I've proposed an edit to make this a "how do I find out" question.  I didn't see the original as a list question, but I hope the new version will work better for you.  I don't think we want a list here; there are probably a few key resources or techniques.  Also, even for people outside the US, large US repositories of information should still be useful -- just not the *only* useful ones.

Comment: I am in the process of open a meta discussion on the general problem of list questions. Currently it might suffice to narrow the scope down to the US?

Comment: [Meta: What do you think about list questions?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/q/146/58).

Comment: I like the current wording of this question, and I think it is relevant.  I vote anti-close.

Comment: Retracting close vote, although I am unsure if the question might still be too broad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the US market,[the FDA website lists recalls](http://www.fda.gov/AnimalVeterinary/SafetyHealth/RecallsWithdrawals/default.htm).  They do not appear to have an RSS feed, but the recalls are date-ordered, so if you get in the habit of checking it periodically, you can still spot what's new.  Even if you're not in the US, this list should still be helpful if your pet food is sold in the US.

The [Canadian Food Inspection Agency](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/about-the-cfia/newsroom/food-recalls-and-allergy-alerts/eng/1299076382077/1299076493846) lists food recalls on its web site but does not call out pet food specifically.  (They also seem to be missing some recalls I expected to see, but this was the best Canada-specific information I could find.)

[PetMD](http://www.petmd.com/news/topics/alert-recalls#.Um2llZTF2GE) has a recalls page that may be global in scope.  They seem to draw from manufacturer notices and not just from governments.

You can also monitor [The Consumerist](http://consumerist.com/), which announces consumer-focused recalls; they provide tags, but there is no simple way to monitor only a portion of what they publish.  You can also join and any relevant pet-enthusiast Facebook groups to hear about recalls via crowd-sourcing.

In addition to checking sites like these, you could set a Google Alert for the name of your pet food, plus the word "recall", which would catch blog mentions and other news sources.  Note that this may generate both false positives and false negatives.

Comment: Is there something similar for Canada?

Comment: @AshleyNunn I added a Canadian govt site; it's harder to use than the FDA one but is the best I could find.  While looking for that I came across PetMD's list, which appears to be global.

Answer (score 1):

the recommendations above are really good.  I'd add that you can also create a [Google News Alert](https://www.google.com/alerts) for a phrase like "[pet type] food recall" or "[pet food brand] food recall".

If you set the alert so that you receive an email as the news happens, you'll get the latest info asap and, if needed, change your pet's diet immediately.